# How to wire up Huey to a Flask application

Tags: python, windows, flask, python-huey

I've read the official docs yet I'm not quite sure I understand how to apply what they tell. Also I've seen [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343459/what-is-the-best-option-for-a-python-3-task-queue-on-windows-now-that-celery-4/43020171#43020171), I also use a factory pattern. Just can't see the whole picture.

1. The connection pool as long as other redis/huey settings may differ depending on the given environment (**development**, **production**). How do we wire **huey** up so we can configure it similar to the Flask application?
2. As long as I understand to fire a task from a view we need to import tasks moudule and call the specific task (call a function passing the sensitive params). Where shoud we instantiate, keep the **huey** instance?
3. Should tasks know about the application dependencies? Should we consider another stripped-down **Flask** app for this matter?

Can you help a little bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I wired it all up.

First off, here's the contents of my project folder:

[image]

1. **Get a stripped-down Flask application to be used by your tasks**. As it was suggested [in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020171/532675) I created a secondary application factory:

   ```
   # global dependencies
   db = SQLAlchemy()

   def create_app_huey(config_name):

       app = Flask(__name__)

       # apply configuration
       app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

       # init extensions
       db.init_app(app)

       return app
   ```
2. **Create tasking package**. Two important files here are **`config.py`** and **`tasks.py`**. [This post helped a lot](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/looking-for-alternative-celery-try-huey). Let's start with configuration. Note, this is very simple approach.

   ```
   # config.py (app.tasking.config)

   import os
   from huey import RedisHuey


   settings__development = {
       'host': 'localhost'
   }

   settings__testing = {
       'host': 'localhost'
   }

   settings__production = {
       'host': 'production_server'
   }

   settings = {
       'development': settings__development,
       'testing': settings__testing,
       'production': settings__production,
       'default': settings__development
   }

   huey = RedisHuey(**settings[os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') or 'default'])
   ```

   Then the **`tasks.py`** module will look like this:

   ```
   import os
   from app.tasking.config import huey
   from app import create_app_huey


   app = create_app_huey(config_name=os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') or 'default')


   @huey.task()
   def create_thumbnails(document):
       pass
   ```
3. **Run the consumer**. Activate your virtual environment. Then run from **cmd** (I'm on Windows):

   > huey_consumer.py app.tasking.config.huey

   Where **`app.tasking.config`** is a **package**.**package**.**module** path (in my case!) and 
   **`huey`** is the name of available (in the config module) **huey** instance. Check your **huey** instance name.

   [Reading this helped](http://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consumer.html).

Comment: Glad you worked it out! I've added a github [flask-huey-example](https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-huey-example) project that others might find useful.