# Queue background tasks in Python application on Windows

Tags: python, windows, redis, python-rq

I am trying to build a Flask application on Windows where user uploads a big Excel file then it is processed in Python which takes 4-5 minutes. I need to process those tasks in background after user uploads the file.

I RQ, Celery, etc. but those are not working on Windows and I have never worked on Linux. I need some advice on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

celery and rq can work on windows but have some trouble

for rq use [this](https://github.com/michaelbrooks/rq-win)

and for celery use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows/62621711#62621711)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's accurate to say that you can't run RQ on Windows, it just has some limitations (as you can in the [documentation](http://python-rq.org/docs/#limitations)).

As you can run [Redis on Windows](https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-2-installing-redis-on-window/), you might want to give a try to other task queues based on Redis. One such example is [huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey). There are at least examples of people who were successful running it on Windows (e.g. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343459/what-is-the-best-option-for-a-python-3-task-queue-on-windows-now-that-celery-4) SO question).

Comment: Thankyou for your input.. I have seen this thread and tried to setup huey with available info.. I am gonna try it once again.. meanwhile more inputs from other experts are most welcome

Comment: well at least when rq worker receives job it pops up this self-explanatory error : `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'fork'`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) Linux Emulation on windows.. and running my RQ worker on WSL..
I am not sure though if I will face any issues in future but as of now its queuing and processing tasks as I desire..

info Might be useful for somebody with same problem